# Why are there only 13 Archimedean solids and not 14?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

I just finished a project on solids for geometry and I couldn’t help but wonder out of curiosity why are there only 13 Archimedean solids and not 14 or more?

Comment: Do you know why there are only 5 Platonic solids?

Comment: Ummm... why did you write "not 14" rather than "not 12"?  ....or not "73"?

Comment: J.W. Tanner I know at each vertex at least 3 faces meet and when they add up the internal angles that meet at a vertex, it must be less than 360 degrees

Comment: It's analogous to, but a bit grungier than, the enumeration of Platonic solids: Any such polyhedron is a triangulation of $S^2$ and thus has $V - E + F = 2$, and the sum of face angles at a given vertex is at most $2\pi$. Now regularity enforces a couple of inequalities that only have a few solutions in positive integers.

Comment: David G. Stork because I want to know why there aren’t 14 or more? I know it’s nothing less than 13 because if you take the 5 Platonic solids truncate them you get 7 Archimedean solids then take those and you get 4 more then you take the Platonic solid and you can snub it so you get the last two all together you get 13 so you can’t have less. That’s why I want to know why it’s not 14 OR more (that includes your “73” because it’s more than 14....)

Comment: Checking the Wikipedia page - not only are there two infinite families that would fit the definition if they weren't specifically excluded, there's also a fourteenth that fits a slight variation on the definition (local symmetry instead of global symmetry). It's all a matter of exactly what rules we apply.

Comment: @jmerry, I've never seen a set of rules that gives the answer 73. 13, yes; 14, yes; infinity, yes; but that's about it.

Comment: Something about King Lear's conversation with his fool about why the seven star are only seven comes to mind.....

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered in this publication : Walsh, T. R. S. ``Characterizing the Vertex Neighbourhoods of Semi-Regular Polyhedra.'' Geometriae Dedicata 1, 117-123, 1972.  [link](https://www.scribd.com/document/29177349/Characterizing-the-Vertex-Neighbourhoods-of-Semi-Regular-Polyhedra-by-T-R-S-Walsh)